# Notificar un nuevo ítem del firebase recylerview?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

```
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item,SandwichViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, SandwichViewHolder>(

            Item.class,
            R.layout.row,
            SandwichViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(SandwichViewHolder viewHolder, Item model, int position) {

            final String sandwich_key = getRef(position).getKey();
            viewHolder.setTitulo(model.getNombreItem());
            viewHolder.setDescripcion(model.getDescripcionItem());
            viewHolder.setImagen(getContext(),model.getImagenItem());

            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mListener.onSandwichSeleccionado(sandwich_key);

                }
            });

        }


    };

    mReciclerSandwich.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    mReciclerSandwich.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {


        }
    });
}



public static class SandwichViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public View mView;


    public SandwichViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;



    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo){

        TextView nombre_personaje = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.titulo_item);
        nombre_personaje.setText(titulo);
        YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomInLeft).duration(300).playOn(nombre_personaje);


    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion){

        TextView descripcion_personaje= (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.descrip_item);
        descripcion_personaje.setText(descripcion);
        YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomInLeft).duration(300).playOn(descripcion_personaje);

    }

    public void setImagen(Context ctx, String imagen){

        ImageView imagen_personaje = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.imag_item);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(imagen).resize(800, 500).into(imagen_personaje);
        YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomInLeft).duration(300).playOn(imagen_personaje);


    }


}
```

Comment: Si se puede, firebase esta pensado específicamente para eso. Que es lo que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: hola tengo mi firebase Recycler adapter (arriba adjunte el código), ya conectado pero no tengo idea de como hacer para que notifique la aplicación cuando yo agregue un item a la base de datos, podrias indicarme que puedo hacer o donde me puedo informar? puede ser que me notifique mediante en FCM o que la aplicación cargue el nuevo ítem diciendo que es nuevo o algo así.

Comment: la sincronización de Firebase es automática, lo que seguramente te esta faltando es refrescar la vista

Comment: a lo que me refiero es que me aparezca una notificacion, en la barra de notificaciones cada vez que se agregue un nuevo item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder enviar un push cuando se modifica la base de datos de Firebase es muy recomendable usar [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), esto te permite escribir pequeños segmentos de javascript hosteados en Firebase que pueden llamarse cuando se da un evento ( en tu caso una [escritura a la base de datos](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)) para luego [llamar al API de FCM desde la misma función](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).